# Help installing vendor software in ubuntu

Tags: installation

I'm appropriately embarrassed to ask this. I have software that I bought 8 years ago and at one point ran on Red Hat linux. I haven't used Linux since then and have forgotten pretty much everything. I have recently intalled Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit) as an operating system and would like to use this software, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to install it. The Software is on a CD. Here's what happens (or doesn't): I click on the CD from the desktop, then I click on the file named install, then I get a screen asking if I want to run install, I click Yes and then nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: No, we can not. You will have to tell us what the name of the software is. At least. In general Redhat software on a medium will -not- work in Ubuntu. Virtualbox with a redhat(centos) install might be possible though.

Comment: It is MATLAB software for Linux/Unix it is not specific to RedHat (that's just what I used at the time).

Comment: Try to run install in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install matlab: it should be inside Ubuntu SoftWare center: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/matlab-support/

There is also a [community faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB) on matlab.